Unable to load Colab
While using Google Colab, I am facing the following error:

Unable to load Colab.
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth
2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
GapiError: Request is missing required authentication credential.
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
authentication credential.
See
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

